# SQL syntax: passing variable to SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, variables, mysql-error-1064

This is my first program and I have done extensive research trying to answer this question and I can not solve the problem:

```
<?php

    include "connect.php";

    if (!$connection)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    $submit = $_POST["submit"];

    if ($submit=="Submit") {
      $date = $_POST["date"];
      $name = $_POST["name"];
      $activity = $_POST["activity"];
      $activity_level = $_POST["activity_level"];

    $find_role = ("SELECT sales_role 
                     FROM role 
                LEFT JOIN USER on user.role_id = role.id 
                    WHERE user.user = '$name'");
    $find_activity_points = ("SELECT $activity_$role 
                                FROM $activity 
                               WHERE activity_level = '$activity_level'"); 

    $role = mysql_query($find_role);

    $activity_points = mysql_query($find_activity_points);
     if ($activity_points !== false) {
     }
      else {
       echo mysql_error ();
       die;
     }

     $convert_activity_points = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($activity_points, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $convert_activity_points[] = $row;
     }



    $set_points = "UPDATE $name SET $activity='$convert_activity_points' WHERE day='$date'";
     mysql_query($set_points);


    } 

    mysql_close($connection);

    ?>
```

And this is the error message that I get when I submit form.php to update.php:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM dial WHERE activity_level='70'' at line 1

P.S. I know there are SQL injection vulnerabilities, but I am the only person using this program and I am using it locally on my computer. I'm okay with the vulnerabilities for now.

Edit: Changed code (I really appreciate the feedback)

```
$find_role = "SELECT sales_role FROM role LEFT JOIN USER on user.role_id=role.id WHERE user.user='$name'";

$find_activity_points = "SELECT %s_%s FROM $activity WHERE activity_level='%d'";    

list($role) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($find_role));

 $activity_points = mysql_query(
     sprintf($find_activity_points, //the main string
         $activity, $role, $activity, $activity_level) //the "arguments"
  );    

    if ($activity_points !== false) {
    }
        else {
            echo mysql_error ();
            die;
    }
```

Updates the table with 0 and doesn't display an error msg. 
Re SQL injection vulnerabilities, see my original PS statement

Comment: Have you looked what sql queries are passed to the mysql by just `echo` them? Also, why did you add parentheses around the strings like `("foo bar")`?

Comment: Is `activity_level` a numeric type? Could it be the quotes around the `70`?

Comment: Possible typo: "$activity_$role"

Comment: You say something from updating but there are only select statements.

Comment: OUTER JOIN with WHERE on the same table equals INNER JOIN!

Comment: What are the parentheses around the query for?

Comment: "I'm okay with the vulnerabilities for now." :-( !!

Comment: "I'm okay with the vulnerabilities for now." That's why we have hackers feeling like gods after hacking systems made by these programmers.

Answer (score 1):

$role isn't defined until later in your program, and even then it's a non-scalar value which will ruin your query as well. You're trying to use the variables before they have values. They don't work that way, once that string is set it will contain the values of those variables at the time it was declared.

You probably want to use sprintf.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
  $find_activity_points = "SELECT %s_%s FROM %s WHERE activity_level='%d'";
```

And then

```
  $activity_points = mysql_query(
     sprintf($find_activity_points, //the main string
         $activity, $role, $activity, $activity_level) //the "arguments"
  );
```

Of course, you still need to get `$role` to be a (scalar) value that can be handled properly within the string. One (somewhat unsafe, but quick) way to do this would be:

```
  list($role) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($find_role));
```

Comment: $find_role = "SELECT sales_role FROM role LEFT JOIN USER on user.role_id=role.id WHERE user.user='$name'";
 
$find_activity_points = "SELECT %s_%s FROM $activity WHERE activity_level='%d'"; 
 
list($role) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($find_role));


 $activity_points = mysql_query(
     sprintf($find_activity_points, //the main string
         $activity, $role, $activity, $activity_level) //the "arguments"
  ); 
 
 if ($activity_points !== false) {
 }
  else {
   echo mysql_error ();
   die;
 }

Comment: Forgive me, the $activity in the $find_activity_points string should be "%s" as well. This has been fixed in my answer, try changing that in your current code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
$find_activity_points = ("SELECT $activity_$role FROM $activity WHERE activity_level='$activity_level'");
```

I can't see anywhere in your code that you define the value of `$role` prior to the execution of the query.

So, assuming that `$activity == 'Eating'` your `SELECT` statement may look something like this:

```
SELECT Eating_$role FROM Eating WHERE activity_level='...'
```

This may lead to your error as I believe MySQL doesn't allow for `$` characters in table/column names.

As [Babiker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372408/sql-syntax-passing-variable-to-sql-query/4372424#4372424) has suggested, you concatenating or using sprintf() can help to resolve some of these various issues.

---

Edit: Answering your question in the comments.

As other's have mentioned, change your `$find_activity_points` line to the something similar to the following:

```
$find_activity_points = ("SELECT " . $activity . "_" . $role . " FROM " . $activity . " WHERE activity_level='" . $activity_level . "'");
```

One thing to keep in mind, is when you do SQL statement concatenation ("SELECT " . $activity . ") like in my example, you open yourself up [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Comment: Perhaps the mistake is even prefixing `role` with a `$`. Elsewhere in the code, she references a `sales_role` field, so perhaps it's just supposed to be `$activity . "_role"` (i.e. `Eating_role` using your example).

Comment: The column name format is activity_role, so the dial table would be dial_sdr, dial_ae, dial_outbound, etc., and the convo table would be convo_sdr, convo_ae, convo_outbound, etc.

Comment: I know that seems like a silly way to set up the database, but I wasn't sure what other structure to use because of the way the contest is set up. Different points are awarded based on role for the same activity. For example:

Comment: SDR: 
7 convos: 1 pt
8-10 convos: 2 pt
11-14 convos: 5 pt
15+ convos: 8 pt

Comment: AE: 5 convos: 1 pt, 6-7 convos: 2 pt, 8-9 convos: 5 pt, 10+ convos: 8 pt. Hence the db structure where column format is activity_role

Comment: @Katherine - No worries. Try to log the generated SQL statement ($find_activity_points) to see what the SQL statement looks like. My assumption is that you have a malformed statement based on the fact that $role isn't being defined until after the statement is generated.

Comment: echo $find_activity_points;

SELECT FROM dial WHERE activity_level='70'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM dial WHERE activity_level='70'' at line 1

so it looks like $activity_$role is not working. how do i change it sow the output of $activity and $role give me the column name activity_role ex. dial_sdr?

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance, I think that "maybe" activity_level data type is not string, but number. So you don't need to place '...' in WHERE activity_level = '$activity_level'

Edit: to be sure about what causes problems, I recommend **logging**, like the example [here](http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/). Just include the class and log your query in a file (very easy), then examine the query itself.

Comment: From form.php

Activity Level:<br />

<input type="text" name="activity_level" size="3" /><br />

<br>

Comment: What I mean is maybe in your database, activity_level is number-type. It's not about the form.

Comment: Whatever, I strongly recommend you log your query before it executed. Then it's much easier to get the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

Concatenating php strings to mysql strings eg:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `someTable` WHERE `someValue`='".$someVar'");
```

- And `$_POST["activity_level"]` is a string with `'` in it.

Solution:

```
"SELECT `".$activity_$role."` FROM `".$activity."` WHERE `activity_level`='".mysql_real_escape_string($activity_level)."'"
```

Comment: It looks like her query is being concatenated/replaced properly, based on the error message she's getting.